# CSS transitions don't work as expected

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

If you see the code here https://jsfiddle.net/ojagwxc0/ the following is not working :

```
.parallax > div .txparallax a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -49px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  background: #3498db;
  width: 126px;
  height: 126px;
  line-height: 126px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
}
```

All I want to see is any kind of "movement" for the words "Select", "Fishing Tackle You Need" & "Mes cuml dia sed inenias ingerto lot aliiqt dolore ipsum commete".

What am I doing wrong? Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try somthing like this. For a transition to work you need to be moving it somehow, for example here I'm, moving it from left:0px; to left:400px on hover:

https://jsfiddle.net/ojagwxc0/2/

```
.parallax > div .txparallax {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left:0px;
}

.parallax > div .txparallax:hover{
    left:400px;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s all ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
    transition: 0.5s all ease;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Brooke, that was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Is there a way to have a transition "auto" & not on "hover"? Actually this is the demo I have in mind http://livedemo00.template-help.com/opencart_53849/index.php?route=common/home

Comment: All of those transitions look to be based either on hover or using javascript in the slider.

Comment: I believe it depends on the offset from top.

Answer (score 0):

you should add an action on hover for ex:

```
 a:hover{
    background-color:red;
}
```

working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ojagwxc0/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible for an auto "movement"? For example the word "Select" to ease from right to left?

Comment: You need CSS animations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations